# File I/O Basics

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working on a school programming lab and I've gotten stuck.  The book is not too helpful in teaching how to format I/O properly, or at least I'm not understanding it properly.  I need a bit of help getting on with the next steps, but here's the full requirements of the program I'm supposed to be making:

> A hotel salesperson enters sales in a text file. Each line contains
>   the following, separated by semicolons: The name of the client, the
>   service sold (such as Dinner, Conference, Lodging, and so on), the
>   amount of the sale, and the date of that event. Write a program that
>   reads such a file and displays the total amount for each service
>   category. Display an error if the file does not exist or the format is
>   incorrect. In addition to the program specifications listed, your
>   program should both print the results as well assend the results to a
>   separate output file.

Example of input.txt:

> Elmer Fudd;Lodging;92.00;11-01-2014
>
> Elmer Fudd;Conference;250.00;11-02-2014
>
> Daffy Duck;Dinner;19.89;11-02-2014
>
> Daffy Duck;Conference;275.00;11-02-2014
>
> Mickey Mouse;Dinner;22.50;11-02-2014
>
> Mickey Mouse;Conference;275.00;11-02-2014

I'm currently stuck on figuring out how to get the file properly loaded and formatted, which I think I did right, but then my professor suggested breaking each into it's own line, but nowhere in my book does it clearly tell how to do that.  Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a coding miracle, I just would like someone to help guide me in the right direction as to what I should do next.  Possibly a better way to handle this situation in a nicely detailed guide?   Nothing fancy though.  Thank you in advance, and here's my current code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Sales
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
            File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            double dinnerTotal = 0;
            double conferenceTotal = 0;
            double lodgingTotal = 0;
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
            while (lineScanner.hasNext())
            {
                String line = in.nextLine(); //Here's where I'm really stuck
                System.out.print(line); //Not to say I'm not stumped all over.
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            lineScanner.close();
    }
}
```

---

From what Jason said, I'm at this now:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Sales
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        double dinnerTotal = 0;
        double conferenceTotal = 0;
        double lodgingTotal = 0;
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(";");
            if(parts[1].equals("Conference")) {
                conferenceTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
            } else if(parts[1].equals("Dinner")) {
                dinnerTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
            } else if(parts[1].equals("Lodging")) {
                lodgingTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
            }
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: why the 2 Scanners? You only need one - the `in` Scanner will do. What I would do is read the file line by line (the `Scanner` will do this nicely) and once you get that working have a look at the `String.split()` method for splitting the line in the various elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to one scanner.

Read each line in total, rather than breaking on the ';'.

Then use `String.split()` to break the line of text apart at the ';' separator.

Then check the second part (zero based index) to retrieve the service category and add the value in the third part to the relevant total.

```
String line = in.nextLine();
String[] parts = line.split(";");
if(parts[1].equals("Conference")) {
    conferenceTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
} else if(parts[1].equals("Dinner")) {
    dinnerTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
} else if(parts[1].equals("Lodging")) {
    lodgingTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
}
```

Comment: thats what I said! :)

Comment: I followed what you said until "Then check the second part (zero based index) to retrieve the service category and add the value in the third part to the relevant total." That made so little sense to me, would you be so kind as to elaborate in simpler terms please. :|

Comment: Look at the code I posted. I split the line into parts based on the ';'. The second part (which is parts[1]) is the service category and the third part (parts[2]) is the price paid.

Comment: So the zero based index will be used to increment through parts?
Or will I be making an index to go through the lines of input.txt? Also, I posted what I changed my code to based on what you said and how I interpreted the placement.

Comment: And what happens when you run it?